# Finding an unknown resistance with superposition

Tags: resistors, superposition

I've been given a problem in which I need to calculate the resistance of an unknown resister \$R_2\$ by using the superposition method. The only other info which I have is that \$R_2\$ needs to be such so that \$I_1=I_2\$ and \$I_3=20\text{ mA}\$.

I hope the image is readable:

[image: Circuit diagram with superposition attempt]

I've set up the three superpositon cases, but at the start of trying to calculate the solution I realised that I had no idea how to proceed with an unkown resistor.

A sort of idea I had was to solve for \$R_2\$ in the first two cases, but then I don't know what to do with the third case.

Comment: Superposition is by far the most complicated method to solve that! Do you really have to go that way?

Comment: Sadly, yes. The problem specifically asks us to use superposition. But I would also be interested in other approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With superposition just write three components of I1 (say I1.1(R2), I1.2(R2) and I1.3(R2) ) each with one single source activated.

Each expression will be function of unknown R2.  Then you sum them up and finally solve this to be 10mA.

I2 will *automatically* be 10mA too for a simple KCL at center node.

Alternatively Ohm's law would solve this right away:

Given I1=10mA Ux at center node will be \$U_\text{x}=U_1-R_1I_1=6.53\,\text{V}-458\,\Omega\times10\,\text{mA}=1.95\,\text{V}\$

On the other hand
$$I_2=\frac{U_2-U_\text{x}}{R_2+R_\text{i}}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
R_2=\frac{U_2-U_\text{x}}{I_2}-R_\text{i}=\frac{8.5\,\text{V}-1.95\,\text{V}}{10\,\text{mA}}-0.4\,\Omega\approx 655\,\Omega$$

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! I'm still pretty poor when it comes to applying Ohm's law (taking an introductory course) but glad that I was at least on the right track for the solution.

Comment: By doing $$10mA = \frac{U_1-U_2}{R_1+R_2+R_i}+\frac{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2+R_i}}{R_1}\cdot I_3$$ and solving for \$R_2\$ am I on the right track then?

Comment: Have a look to I3 term, there's something wrong, it is dimensionally wrong, you have A/ohm^2 which is not a current. Maybe thinking of current divider helps you...

Comment: Oh I forgot a -1.. $$10mA = \frac{U_1-U_2}{R_1+R_2+R_i}+\frac{(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2‌​+R_i})^{-1}}{R_1} \cdot I_3$$ Does that look better?

Comment: Not yet it's the opposite and rather complicated way too. I just remember the current divider rule *..times the other, over the sum..*, so in your case \$ \ldots +\frac{R_2+R_\text{i}}{R_1+R_2+R_\text{i}}I_3\$

Comment: Ok  now I'm confused. I thought that $$\frac{I}{I_1}=\frac{R_{sum}}{R_1}$$  was the current divider rule.   And then is not \$ \ldots +\frac{R_2+R_\text{i}}{R_1+R_2+R_\text{i}}I_3\$ for \$ I_2\$ ?

Comment: My thought process was that \$ R_1\$ is in parallel with \$ R_2+R_i \$

Comment: I am afraid this is getting a little too long to be hosted in"comments", however we have: $$I_1=I_3\frac{R_2+R_i}{R_1+R_2+R_i}$$ and $$I_2=I_3\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2+R_i}$$  then might discuss of why and how on a different question.